# Xaml TextBlock not displaying unique characters

Tags: c#, xaml

I have a string `NonEncodedCharactersMessage` that has the value:

```
"Invalid Characters in Spool Name:"
```

In the Xaml, I have a TextBlock that is Binded to the the string value "NonEncodedCharactersMessage".

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="3"
                   Grid.Column="0"
                   Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                   Margin="4,-5,0,0"
                   Text="{Binding NonEncodedCharactersMessage}"
                   Visibility="{Binding ContainsNonEncodedCharacterVisibility}"
                   Foreground="Red"
                   FontSize="10"
                   FontStyle="Italic" />
```

In my code I am appending unique characters so the string becomes

```
"Invalid Characters in Spool Name: は,で,し,た"
```

and when the Xaml Is rendered at run time, the text is displayed as

```
"Invalid Characters in Spool Name:   "
```

So it seems that Xaml is unable to display unique characters.

How can I get Xaml TextBlock to render the string?

EDIT: This is how the property is being set.

```
char[] invalidChars = (SpoolName != null) ?  SpoolName.ToCharArray().Distinct().Where(p => !p.IsEncodable()).ToArray() : new char[] { };
            NonEncodedCharactersMessage = $"Invalid characters in Spool Name:  {string.Join(",", invalidChars )}";
```

What is interesting is that when I set the string as

```
"Invalid Characters in は, でしたSpool Name:"
```

It is able to appear. It is only when the string value is appended with special characters, the appended special characters are not rendered in the xaml.

Comment: Your text can be rendered or not no matter how it is provided (directly or bound). Can you make sure, that the `TextBlock` is using an appropriate `FontFamily` when you run the program. A reason for the described behaviour might be, that it inherits a font, that is not suitable for displaying all characters. BTW: Not sure, what you mean by "When ContainsNonEncodedCharacterVisibility is true, the string is displayed." vs "...at run time...".

Comment: As shown above, the TextBlock is not using a FontFamily.

Sorry that was not clear, what I meant by the string being displayed, is that when I'm stepping through the code, I can see the full string being with the unique characters being displayed when examined in the debugger. It's just no appearing in the Xaml UI.

I tested again and hardcoded the string with the Unique character and it actually appeared. It's only when I append it that it does not appear. The unique characters are appending successfully though

Comment: Yes, as the `TextBlock` is not specifying a `FontFamily` it might inherit a non-suitable value from it's environment. That's why I asked to explicitly specify something suitable (`Segoe UI` worked in my test).

Comment: @JürgenRöhr I have the TextBlock FontFamily using Segoe UI however the appended unique characters still do not appear in the TextBlock. It seems like the very act of appending the string with Unique Characters causes the unique characters to not appear. Otherwise if the original string had unique characters without appending, they appear on the UI. 

Hope that made sense.

Comment: I've just created a minimum sample of your case ... and everything works. Can you please add the code of your view model/the text blocks data context which contains `NonEncodedCharactersMessage`.